# Suggested way to split up dimensions with parent-child

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, dimensional-modeling

Let's say I have the following 'fact' that I want to build into a multi-dimensional model:

`MOVIE_SALES`

- Year
- Studio
- Movie
- Amount

So, for example, two entries in this would be:

```
Studio          Movie       Year        Sales
Paramout        Godfather   2020        $ ...
Paramout        Godfather   2021        $ ...
```

The dimensions for this are the `Sutiod`, `Movie`, and `Year`.

Should `Studio` and `Movie` be the same dimension because a `movie` is a child of a `studio` (ignoring edge cases), or should these be separate dimensions? In other words, when one dimension/attribute is a child of another in a fact table, when should those be broken out into the same dimension table, and when should they be broken out into different dimension tables?

Answer (score 2):

You break them down depending on the grain of the properties of each dimension.

If you have Studio, Studio Location, Studio Owner, etc.. and Movie, Director, Studio, Year Released, Genre, etc.. to me that's 2 dimensions, and you have yourself a snowflake schema.

If you have only Movie, Director, Studio, Year Released, Genre then studio is just an attribute on your Movie dimension.

Also your fact shouldn't need to have a reference to Studio, as you can get to that via Movie.